# Sharding mechanism (like SQL Azure Federations) in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'd like to ask if there exist any sharding mechanism (like SQL Azure Federations in Cloud) but in SQL Server 2012 .
I've searched a lot but I couldn't find any appropriate solution that resembles Federations. There is AlwaysOn but it's not the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature is not in the boxed product in SQL Server 2012. There are many ways to scale reads but [merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) and [distributed partitioned views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191185%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) seem to still be the only viable out-of-the-box solutions for scaling writes. Note that the latter doesn't seem to be officially documented separately in SQL Server 2012 - it has [all been condensed into the `CREATE VIEW` topic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).